# Strongly typed View: Model class not listed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create strongly typed view from model class `N1Process`. I did compile the solution, before attempting to add View. But can't locate this N1Process model in the add View wizard.

[image]

```
namespace GetPathOfRunningProcess.Models
{
    public class N1Process
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does it has to do anything with the namespace `GetPathOfRunningProcess.Models` where `N1Process` has been defined ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your N1Process normal class or static class? what class it inherits?

Comment: @Mark This is normal class & no inheritance. Posted code above.

Comment: I just tried a close & reopen VS - this fixed it for me.

Comment: another thing to check is that Template isn't set to Empty (No Model) - rather than Empty. (or something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type in the path in the wizard or just add

```
@model N1Process
```

to the top of your view file.

(You'll probably need the fully qualified name in the @model statement).

Answer (score 0):

Build your Application and it show the models